# How to generate Elasticsearch security users via Ansible

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, elasticsearch-x-pack

We just installed Elasticsearch 7.x. We want to use the `x-pack` security module. We already automated everything via Ansible but we have a problem creating/setting the built in users with password:

ElsticSearch how to:

> Run on system: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive or auto.

Then you are asked for a password for each user in ElasticSearch. Are there any possibilities to automate this? Like some autoanswer question in Ansible or anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `interactive` mode and ansible `expect` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html

Answer (score 1):

```
  hosts: all
  name: "Elasticsearch with SSL/TLS enabled"
  roles: 
    - 
      role: elastic.elasticsearch
  vars: 
    es_api_port: 9200
    es_config: 
      action.destructive_requires_name: true
      bootstrap.memory_lock: true
      cluster.name: lab
      discovery.seed_hosts: "0.0.0.0:9300"
      discovery.type: single-node
      http.port: 9200
      indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 8192
      network.host: "0.0.0.0"
      node.data: true
      node.master: true
      node.ml: false
      node.name: lab1
      reindex.remote.whitelist: "*:*"
      search.max_buckets: 250000
      transport.port: 9300
      xpack.ilm.enabled: true
      xpack.ml.enabled: false
      xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: true
      xpack.monitoring.collection.interval: 30s
      xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
      xpack.security.audit.enabled: false
      #xpack.security.enabled: true
      xpack.sql.enabled: true
      xpack.watcher.enabled: false
    es_api_basic_auth_username: "elastic"
    es_api_basic_auth_password: "changeme"
    es_data_dirs: 
      - /opt/elasticsearch/data
    es_heap_size: 2g
    es_plugins: 
      - 
        plugin: ingest-attachment
    es_validate_certs: false
    es_version: "7.17.0"
    es_users:
      native:
        elastic:
          password: helloakash1234
        kibana_system:
          password: hellokibana1234
        logstash_system:
          password: hellologs1234
```

This works fine for me!!

```
    es_users:
      native:
        elastic:
          password: helloakash1234
```

With the above mentioned code the username will be "elastic" and the password will be "helloakash1234"

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `auto` mode, then random passwords are generated and written to the console that you can maybe read.

Another solution is to [call](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) the [Change password API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-change-password.html) in order to change user passwords after the fact.

Comment: Hi,

is there any option to run it like:

/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto -y ???
I dont want to be prompted.

Comment: choosing `auto` will not prompt you, only `interactive` will

Comment: I have tried to do it via API and got 

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"failed to authenticate user [elastic]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"failed to authenticate user [elastic]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}[root@DCVMESRMSTDEV01 ~]# curl -uelastic -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/ki

Comment: Hi @JiříŠafář, you should avoid diluting this type of info in comments. Edit your question instead to enrich it with what you have tried and is still causing problems. You will get a much better chance to get your question answered accurately.